# Error message: Error in data$CVDSTRK3 : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Tags: r, data-science, data-analysis

```
Q<-patients_with_stroke <- data[data$CVDSTRK3==1,]
max_numwomen<-max(patients_with_stroke$NUMWOMEN, na.rm = TRUE)
max_numwomen
```

Please help. I tried to find the highest value for number of adult women in the household where someone has ever had a stroke and then summarise the value in a variable called max_numwomen   thank you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you make your post [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by providing your dataset using `dput(data)`?

Comment: There is a function in R called `data()`. If you don't have a variable defined called `data`, and you try to take a subset, as you are doing when you call `data[data$CVDSTRK3==1,]`, it will try to take a subset of a function. That doesn't make sense because a function is "not subsettable," as the error message is basically saying. So you must not have created a variable called `data` before you tried to subset it.